# Can't activate SWT Listener

Tags: java, swt, getter-setter

I am trying to do something simple which is to open a view called LoginForm whenever I push a button (MenuItem) in my main view (Monitor). I have a listener that is outside of the views in a package called controller and it gets the button from Monitor add the functionality of opening LoginForm:

```
    public void initController() {

        class FF4JListener implements SelectionListener {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent event) {

                new LoginForm(monitor);

            }

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(final SelectionEvent event) {
                new LoginForm(monitor);

            }

        }

        monitor.getFF4jMItem().addSelectionListener(new FF4JListener());

    }
}
```

I have the monitor as an input for LoginForm because I tried to use the same display in both window otherwise it doesn't work I get a **"multiple displays"** error
Problem is when I click on the button that supposed to open LoginForm it simply doesn't do anything. And whenever I close the program it runs this error:  **"Widget is disposed"**.
I really don't understand why it isn't doing anything and I've been struggling with this for quite while now.

Here is the relevant part of **Monitor** which is the main window:

```
public class Monitor {
    
    Display display;

    Shell shellMain;

    Menu menuBar, fileMenu, subMenu, subFF4J;

    MenuItem fileMenuHeader;

    MenuItem fileContextItem, contextFF4JItem, dashboardItem;

    MenuItem ff4jMItem;

    Label label;

    Label labelHost, labelPassword, labelUsername;

    Text host, username, password, text;

    public Monitor() {

        display = new Display();
        shellMain = new Shell(display);
        shellMain.setText("Dashboard");
        shellMain.setSize(1024, 1024);

        label = new Label(shellMain, SWT.CENTER);
        label.setBounds(shellMain.getClientArea());

        menuBar = new Menu(shellMain, SWT.BAR);
        shellMain.setMenuBar(menuBar);
        fileMenuHeader = new MenuItem(menuBar, SWT.CASCADE);
        fileMenuHeader.setText("&File");

        fileMenu = new Menu(shellMain, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
        fileMenuHeader.setMenu(fileMenu);

        fileContextItem = new MenuItem(fileMenu, SWT.CASCADE);
        fileContextItem.setText("Context");

        subMenu = new Menu(shellMain, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
        fileContextItem.setMenu(subMenu);

        ff4jMItem = new MenuItem(subMenu, SWT.PUSH);
        ff4jMItem.setText("FF4J");

        shellMain.setMenuBar(menuBar);
        shellMain.open();

    }

    public void refresh() {
        while (!shellMain.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    } 

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new Monitor();

    }

    public MenuItem getFF4jMItem() {
        return ff4jMItem;
    }

    public void setFF4jMItem(final MenuItem ff4jMItem) {
        this.ff4jMItem = ff4jMItem;
    }

    public Display getDisplay() {
        return display;
    }

    public void setDisplay(final Display display) {
        this.display = display;
    }
}
```

here is what i think is the relevant part of the **LoginForm** code:

```
public class LoginForm {
    static Monitor monitor;
    Shell shellLoginForm = new Shell(monitor.getDisplay());
    //some code

    public LoginForm(final Monitor m) {
        // some code
        while (!shellLoginForm.isDisposed()) {
            if (!monitor.getDisplay().readAndDispatch()) {
                monitor.getDisplay().sleep();
            }
        }
        monitor.getDisplay().dispose();
    }
}
```

and I bring everything together with AppContext

```
public class AppContext {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final FF4jContext ff4jContext = new FF4jContext();
        final Monitor monitor = new Monitor();
        monitor.refresh();
        final FF4JContextController ff4jController = new 
        FF4JContextController(monitor, ff4jContext);
        ff4jController.initController();

    }

}
```

Comment: It is impossible to say what the problem is from a couple of scraps of the program. You need to show us a complete [mre]. Cut your code down to the minimum that shows the problem.

Comment: I've added as much as it was necessary so anyone could reproduce it by simply copy pasting hope that helps

Comment: You call `monitor.refresh()` before `initController` - but `monitor.refresh()` is the main SWT loop and will not finish until the main shell closes.